# Kango won't build the IE plugin

Tags: internet-explorer, plugins, kango-framework

I have created a plug-in in kango, and when I run the build command it builds the firefox and chrome plugins, IE plugin is not build and it says: "Contact extensions@kangoextensions.com to enable IE support", tried on linux and windows and on both the same result. Any ideas?

Comment: You should mark the below answer as correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Kango supports extensions for all the major browsers. But, the major drawback of Kango extension is that it builds the extension for open source non-profitable project like Chrome,firefox. etc.For IE,you have to buy a commercial license. This is the reason behind its asking you to contact the kango team to buy license for IE extension